# Show bootstrap modal window if user is not authenticated MVC

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to show a bootstrap modal window when a user is not authenticated in my application.

It doesn't seem to work.

Its when I click button for uploading file it invokes jQuery script and checks whether user is authenticated or not.

**I tried-**

```
 <a id="upload-card" class="btn btn-success btn-large">Upload a Ranger Card</a>
```

**jQuery-**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $('#upload-card').click(function () {
            if ("@Request.IsAuthenticated" == false) {
                $('#modal-authentication').modal("show");
            }
            else {
                window.location.href = "/Upload/Account/";
            }

        });
    });

</script>
```

**Bootstrap modal window-**

```
<div id="modal-authentication" class="modal hide fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog"
    aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">
            ×</button>
        <h3 id="myModalLabel">
            Modal header</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
        <center>@Html.Partial("_SharedLogOn")</center>
    </div>
</div>
```

Help me solving this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you try like this -

```
if ('@Request.IsAuthenticated' == 'False')
```

Comment: Why its not happening in case of `false`?